# Calculating distance to a feature from a reference line

Tags: shapefile, arcgis-desktop, geoprocessing, features, measurements

I have multiple shapefiles, each containing a coastline for a specific year. I want to calculate the perpendicular distance to the shoreline from a fixed vertical reference line.

Please recommend me the best tool (in ArcGIS-Desktop) to find out the perpendicular distance from each point (or a definite number of multiple points) on the reference line to the shoreline shapefile. I have included a screenshot to describe what I am planning to achieve.

I am hoping to be able to create 1 custom point per 100m on the reference line and then calculate the distance to the shoreline from these points.

[image: Measuring distance from Reference line to Shoreline]

Comment: This is two different questions, although you might not have intended it. The diagram shows a computation of the distance *from a point* to a line. Your last paragraph asks to compute distances *from points on the line* back to a feature. Those will not be the same! Which of these two operations do you actually want?

Answer (score 2):

Does the vertical line always have the same X value within the projection you are using?

If so you can find the distance by calculating the difference between the X value of the vertical line, and the X value of the point.

The following field calculator python snippet would calculate this:

```
abs(!SHAPE.CENTROID.X! - 50000)
```

This assumes that your vertical line has an X value of 50,000.

Answer (score 1):

[Near](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000001q000000) tool determines the distance from each feature in the input features to the nearest feature in the near features, within the search radius.

Comment: Yes, I did check the Near tool. But, unfortunately, I think it does not solve my problem as I am interested in determining the distance in a particular direction (see figure) and not just the nearest feature (as given by the Near tool).

Answer (score 0):

this thread might be useful to you:
[Creating point file along line (trail) at regular distances (0.20 miles) using ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41307/creating-point-file-along-line-trail-at-regular-distances-0-20-miles-using-a)

once you've split your line into points you can run the Near tool