# Alternative profile graphs for ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, 3d-analyst, profile

Anybody know an alternative to profile graph option for ArcGIS 10.2? 3D Analyst can produce a profile, however it's extremely bare bones and doesn't include a scaling option.

Does anybody know an effective alternative to make a profile graph that can be added to ArcMap layouts?

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere at the bare bone 3D Analyst graph is an option to export the underlying data and use Excel or others to create the graph.

If you want to avoid manually made (clicked) profile graphs with the 3D Analyst it is also possible to use existing line features.
You create a [equal distributed point file along a line](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41307/how-to-create-a-point-file-along-a-line-trail-at-regular-distances-0-20-miles) for which you want to create the profile. Then use [Extract Values to Points](http://help.arcgis.com/de/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z0000002t000000) (requires Spatial Analyst) to write the raster height values to your point file. Since the distance between the points is equal you can use Excel or whatever you want and create a graph from the data table of the point file.

It is not necessary to use Spatial Analyst e.g. [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3538/extract-raster-values-at-points?rq=1).