# Generating Points Along Lines not starting at the start of my line feature

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, point, line

I am trying to generate chainage points in 50m intervals on a road system including the start and end of the line. Each road is its own single continuous line and while attempting to solve my issue, I have tried using the entire feature class, as well as using one selected feature.

The first time I ran the "Generate Points Along Lines" tool with "Include Endpoints" checked on, the first point wasn't even located on the line and was floating above, skewing my chainages. I re-ran this tool with only a single road selection with "Include Endpoints" selected, and the first point was now located about 9m from the start. Whether I select the "include endpoints" option or not, the points start generating about 9m from the beginning of the feature instead of the the actual beginning and do not include an end point. I then decided to create a new feature of the road by tracing the original in an attempt to remove any error from merged multipart features, but the results are still the same.

After researching other peoples questions using the tool, I would just like to go ahead and say I am using a projected CS of NAD83 10N on 10.8 ArcMap Desktop. I am also stuck using the Basic license at the discretion of my company so my tools are limited.

Is this a tool malfunction? Is there a way to get around this or perhaps another way?

Comment: Check if your lines are single- or multipart features.

Comment: I made sure I blew the lines apart to create single features the second time I ran the tool with no change in results. I also created a new single line to test it also with no change in results.

Comment: Are projections the same for features and map document? What happens when you do feature vertices to points (both ends)?

Comment: Perhaps try my very old script https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/169908/densifying-polyline-to-generate-points-at-set-distances-using-arcmap#169936